# jQuery; Targeting HTML after .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At /page there is the following `<h1>hello world</h1>`

On my homepage I am using;

```
            $(function() {
                $('#content').load('/page');
            });
```

After loading, I get the following in the DOM.

```
            <div id="content">
                <h1>Hello world</h1>
            </div>
```

I'd would like to add a class to this newly loaded h1, so I try;

```
            $('#content h1').addClass('world');
```

This fails because h1 was inserted after the page was loaded. How do I find and target newly added HTML?

Comment: [Check the API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/), load accepts a `complete` parameter which can be a function that executes after the data has been loaded. I'm pretty sure this is a dupe though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery load and then edit loaded content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213497/jquery-load-and-then-edit-loaded-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you can use the `complete` attribute of the `.load()` function.  Read more here http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$(function() {
     $('#content').load('/page', function() {
         $('#content h1').addClass('world');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/load/), load method receives a function that is executed when it´s done:

```
$(function() {
    $('#content').load('/page', function(){
       $('#content h1').addClass('world');
    });
});
```

Instead of the alert, add whatever you want to do with H1

Comment: What is `#result` and he wants to load `/page` not `ajax/test.html`, try to make it fit into the question, don't copy paste from the documentation